# How can I pattern match in a function where a Map has a key with the passed in value?

Tags: erlang

So I am creating an IRC server, and I have a function that removes a user from a Map.  The idea is to use pattern matching, so one version of a function gets called if the user is in the map and another function gets called otherwise.

My first idea was to do the following:

```
remove_user_from_channel(User, Channel=#channel_details{users = UserMap=#{User := _}}) ->
  Channel#channel_details{users = maps:remove(User, UserMap)}.
```

However, this fails to compile with the error `variable 'User' is unbound`.

Is there any way to accomplish this with function level pattern matching?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do pattern matching for map keys in a function head but you can do in `case`:

```
remove_user_from_channel(User, Map) ->
  case Map of
    Channel = #channel_details{users = UserMap = #{User := _}} ->
      Channel#channel_details{users = maps:remove(User, UserMap)};
    _ ->
      other
   end.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
remove_user_from_channel(User, Channel=#channel_details{users = UserMap}) ->
    case maps:is_key(User, UserMap) of
        true -> Channel#channel_details{users = maps:remove(User, UserMap)};
        false -> ok
    end.
```

I think you can't use match pattern in function level, but you can use `is_key(Key, Map) -> boolean()` to check `User` is in `UserMap`.
Here is the link:
http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#is_key-2