# Map pattern matching in function head with variable

Tags: erlang

I wrote a simple function to get the number of occurrence of each character in a string:

```
count([], Result) ->
  Result;

count([Head|Tail], #{Head := Count} = Result) ->
  count(Tail, Result#{Head := Count +1});

count([Head|Tail], Result) ->
  count(Tail, Result#{Head => 1}).
```

But apparently something is wrong with the pattern matching of the map.
I get `variable 'Head' is unbound`.From the doc it doesn't seem to be an illegal pattern and does work with variables or lists.

So, am I doing something wrong (if yes can you explain what/why) or is it something else that has not been implemented for the maps yet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use pattern matching like that on the map's key in the function head - take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808874/pattern-matching-key-in-erlang-maps), or [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416053/how-can-i-pattern-match-in-a-function-where-a-map-has-a-key-with-the-passed-in-v).

However you can use the `is_key/2` function to check if it is present.

Alternatively, you could use the default part of [maps:get/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#get-3):

```
count([], Result) ->
  Result;

count([Head|Tail], Result) ->
  Count = maps:get(Head, Result, 0),
  count(Tail, Result#{Head => Count + 1}).
```

Or use [update_with/4](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#update_with-4) with a setter function.

Comment: Does it mean that function heads are evaluated from right to left ? If it was evaluated from left to right Head would be set before evaluating the map pattern.

Comment: They are evaluated from left to right, just maps are bit special when it comes to pattern matching. And IIRC they are still labelled as 'experimental' when if comes to functionality around maps.

Comment: @ITChap Here's a [more comprehensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106543/illegal-pattern-in-map-of-erlang) answer on supported features for maps for function heads